# Trying to Install AWS CLI, stuck on a step

Tags: command-line, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

Im trying to install aws for the mac command line, I guess I dont understand what I need to do I installed the aws bundle with wget on the terminal, unziped it did everything, but when I need to configure my credentials nothing comes up when I put aws configure..

Here are the Instructions:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-set-up.html
Here is what is ouputed

```
an$ aws configuration
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/aws", line 15, in <module>
    import awscli.clidriver
  File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 31, in <module>
    from awscli.help import ProviderHelpCommand
  File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/help.py", line 20, in <module>
    from docutils.core import publish_string
  File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils/core.py", line 20, in <module>
    from docutils import frontend, io, utils, readers, writers
  File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils/frontend.py", line 41, in <module>
    import docutils.utils
  File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils/utils/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    import docutils.io
  File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils/io.py", line 18, in <module>
    from docutils.utils.error_reporting import locale_encoding, ErrorString, ErrorOutput
  File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils/utils/error_reporting.py", line 47, in <module>
    locale_encoding = locale.getlocale()[1] or locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
  File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 511, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 443, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

Any Ideas_?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

try adding below lines to `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Don't forget to close your terminal and open it again after you edited your file.

Comment: Additionally you can run "source ~/.bash_profile " for not having to close and reopen your terminal

Comment: Can you give an explanation of the solution?

Comment: This solved my issue after install `aws-cli` using python 2.7 on Mac OS X. Thank you!

Comment: This worked me for python  -m spacy download en_core_web_md

Answer (score 4):

**Installing AWSCLI in Windows Machine**

I had similar issue with Windows 10 (64 bit). Python 3.5 and Python 2.7 are installed in my PC. I was getting `ImportError: No module named awscli.clidriver`.

Then I added `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\Scripts` in environment path variable and removed Python 2.7 from the environment path variable. Now I can successfully use `awscli`.

I have created a step by step AWSCLI installation guide in this Github repository: https://github.com/arsho/installation/tree/master/awscli_installation.

Answer (score 3):

I had to install EKS supported version and I ended up getting it to work with ignoring `six`:

```
$ pip3 install awscli --ignore-installed six
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case nothing worked, untill i gave more permissions, i run aws command with a non root user

```
chown amzadm.root  /usr/bin/aws
chown amzadm.root -R /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
chown amzadm.root -R /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/awscli/
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding a line to the 'aws' script just before the import (line 19). So now the file reads:

```
sys.path.append('/Users/<username>/.local/lib/aws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/')
import awscli.clidriver
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me. In /.barshrc file

```
export AWS_DEFAULT_OUTPUT="json"
```