# Linux commands error as if they were python modules

Tags: python, command-line-interface, archlinux

I'm running arch and when I try to use `aws` in the terminal I get a python-like error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/aws", line 19, in <module>
    import awscli.clidriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awscli'
```

This happened for `pip` as well which I resolved by `python -m ensurepip` but I don't know why it was like that in the first place. I even tried explicitly adding the path to `aws` to my `PATH` to no avail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [awscli fails to work: No module named 'awscli'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43873663/awscli-fails-to-work-no-module-named-awscli)

Comment: Well, even the pip command is showing this issue. I don't see why it's trying to run these normal terminal programs through python.

Answer (score 0):

Well, pip and other applications are in fact python programs. Apparently you just lack the 'awscli' module. A first try would be just install this module.

Comment: Well, even the pip command is showing this issue. I don't see why it's trying to run these normal terminal programs through python.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

```
sudo pip install awscli --force-reinstall --upgrade
```

Comment: Well, even the pip command is showing this issue. I don't see why it's trying to run these normal terminal programs through python.